# blank screen forever trying to switch users on Linux Mint 16 Petra (often)

Tags: linux, laptop, linux-mint, login, fast-user-switching

Our netbook running Mint 16 (all up-to-date) has two users.  Since first installing, we have run into two very similar problems going Menu -> Log Out -> Switch User, or going Menu -> System Tools -> New Login, although sometimes it works as expected and just brings one either to the login menu you get on bootup, or asks for the password for the other user.

CASE 1: Sometimes the screen goes all black, no cursor or anything, and will remain that way I suppose forever (longest I left it was 15 minutes one time).  I can go Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get a text console and then (without logging in) Ctrl+Alt+F7 to return to the GUI, at which point it seems to break out of whatever it was stuck in, but rather than a login menu or password for the other user, it asks for the password for the user I was trying to switch *from*.  So I have to enter that password and then try switching again, which usually works.

CASE 2: Like CASE 1, but switching back to the GUI with Ctrl+Alt+F7 does not help anything: that screen remains blank no matter how much switching I do.  Very occasionally, the F7 screen actually is in text mode rather than GUI, and might have some messages on it.  (The last time this happened, the message was something about a wrong MAC address, and it kept repeating every couple seconds or so.  The computer had been in sleep mode, or attempted to be--had its lid shut, which is configured to Suspend with the lid shut on AC power--and had been reawakened by opening the lid then hitting Ctrl, and a few seconds later had attempted to switch users via the New Login method, with the other user not being logged in.)

I have this happen maybe 1/3 - 1/2 of the time.  So far I can't figure out what conditions make it more or less likely to happen.  It doesn't seem to make a difference if the other user is already logged in or not.  The "New Login" way seems to work well more often than the "Switch User" way.

I guess my question is twofold: is there a way to **just make it always work the way it should**?  If not, what commands would I need to run from the console to fix CASE 2 so that when this happens **I don't end up having to restart the computer** and lose all my open programs and such, which takes a long time on an HP Mini 1101 and is generally annoying to the other person I wanted to borrow the computer from for a moment?

Answer (score -1):

try upgrading your system to linux mint 17 :

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Is this just a wild guess or can you back it up? Please edit your answer to point to a reference stating that is a version issue 16 that is resolved in version 17. If it is only a guess, your answer is nothing even worth begin a comment.

Comment: @JanDoggen thanks, I'd like to know this too.  There's always a risk upgrading, so I wouldn't want to take it if it won't even fix the bugs I do know about.